# Delete elements in a list and retaining the size of a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let suppose I have a list `A = [None, None, None, None, None, None, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. As of now the size of the list is 10. Now I want to delete a specific element say `1` but at the same time I want that `1` should be replace by `None` and the size of the list is retained. Deleting `1` should not change the size of the list to 9.

Comment: Just .. assign the index the desired value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove only the first element, you can do this

```
A[A.index(1)] = None
```

But, if you want to replace all the `1`s in the list, you can use this list comprehenesion

```
A = [None if item == 1 else item for item in A]
```

If you want to do inplace replacement, you can do it like this (thanks to @Jonas)

```
A[:] = [None if item == 1 else item for item in A]
```

You can write generic functions, like this

```
A, B = [None,None, None, None, None, None, 1, 1, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1]

def replace(input_list, element, replacement):
    try:
        input_list[input_list.index(element)] = None
    except ValueError, e:
        pass
    return input_list

def replace_all(input_list, element, replacement):
    input_list[:] = [replacement if item == element else item for item in input_list]
    return input_list

print replace(A, 1, None)
print replace_all(B, 1, None)
```

**Output**

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 1, 3, 4]
[None, None, None]
```

Comment: Note that the second statement is not *in place*, in contrast to the first (and the usual ``del`` operator which does not apply to this question). To make the second statement *in place*, you have to change the left-hand-side to ``A[:]`` (just sayin’, might cause confusion).

Comment: Inplace replacement is worth the extra resources only when the list **A** is referenced by another objects

Answer (score 1):

If you only know the value, this will replace the *first* occurrence:

```
A[A.index(1)] = None
```

If you know the index:

```
A[6] = None
```